# how to write a view page that displays a list returned from a python method using django

Tags: python, html, django, django-views

I have this method in my views.py file that prints a list returned from the method rangeOfList().
I would like to display that on the html page that it redirects the browser to (result.html). 
How would I write that?

```
def contact(request):
if request.method == 'POST': # If the form has been submitted...
    form = ContactForm(request.POST) # A form bound to the POST data

    if form.is_valid():
        form = form.cleaned_data
        parameters = organize(form)
        listToPrint = rangeOfList(parameters['money'][2], parameters['money'][4], 'total_money')



    return HttpResponseRedirect('result') # Redirect after POST
else:
    form = ContactForm() # An unbound form

return render(request, 'crunchApp/contact.html', {
    'form': form,
})
```

Comment: Could you use something like `reverse` and pass `listToPrint` as an arg? I've never tried it, but seems like it might work. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/#django.core.urlresolvers.reverse

Comment: You can use HttpResponseRedirect('/result/'), or redirect('/result/')

Comment: how would I specify the html file to redirect to then? @themanatuf

Comment: and how do I include listToPrint that way? @karthikr

Comment: @Santiago you'd have to create a view function for result and pass that view name to `reverse` along with `listToPrint` as an arg to it. From there you can render whatever HTML output you want. See this example: http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/385/

Comment: I just did this and it didnt work:
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('results', chosen)) # Redirect after POST


    def results(request):
    return render_to_response('crunchApp/results.html')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add it to the [session](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/sessions/):

```
request.session['the_list'] = listToPrint
return redirect('result/')
```

Make sure you have activated the [request template context processor](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/#django-core-context-processors-request) then in your template:

```
{% for i in request.session.the_list %}
   {{ i }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: I cant seem to get this to work... how do I activate the request template context processor?? @Burhan

Comment: Did you already try the link(s) in the answer - they are documentation links to help you along the way.

Comment: yes, where do I activate it? in the TEMPLATE_LOADERS of setting.py or somewhere on the html page?

Comment: In your `settings.py`, add it to `TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS`.

Comment: When I try this, I get the error that 'redirect()' is not a method. It says "global name redirect has not been defined"
Another question, what exactly does HttpResponse() do? It seems like it gives a value to a response variable but I am unsure of how it works. Could this method help me out?

Comment: Add `from django.shortcuts import redirect` to the top of your `views.py` file.

Comment: sorry but this is still not working. Is there another way to do this? Will the methods I described above help me or is using sessions the only way to do this? @Burhan

Comment: Sessions is the proper way; you should open another question and detail the error you are getting.